# Build error when using ament_python ROS 2 package

Tags: roslaunch, ros-humble, colcon, ament

After adding following line to the `setup.py`:

```
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob(os.path.join('launch', '*launch.[pxy][yma]*')))
```

I get following error when calling `colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select <package_name>` :

```
Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'import sys;from contextlib import suppress;exec("with suppress(ImportError):    from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers    import SpecifierSet");exec("with suppress(ImportError):    from packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet");from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    \'setup.py\', script_args=(\'--dry-run\',), stop_after=\'config\');skip_keys = (\'cmdclass\', \'distclass\', \'ext_modules\', \'metadata\');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith(\'_\') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data[\'metadata\'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in (\'license_files\', \'provides_extras\')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode(\'utf-8\'))']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I don't really know what could be wrong, because in other package, I use same definition and it works. Error message is also not really helpful :/

I'm using `setuptools 58.2.0` and you can check full code/repository [here](https://github.com/fzoric8/uam_ros2_pkg).

Thank you for your help.